# Why there are some data in cuda:0 when I indicate cuda:1 to train my model?

Tags: pytorch

I am training my model in cuda:1, and I find that there are some data in cuda:0.

[image]

What's more, if I use different hyperparameters to train my model in cuda:0 when training in cuda:1, then both training procedure become very slow. And the predicted result becomes not so good as just train my model in cuda:1.

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post the python script, this is likely where your issue is

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the data in cuda:0 while training on cuda:1, the processes have the same PID, so it's likely that you are allocating by mistake some data in the cuda:0 GPU.

For the slowness during the training phase, it might be connected to the CPU, which acts as a bottleneck. When training, the CPU is basically preparing the data (through the DataLoader) to be fed to the GPUs. It's likely that GPUs wait on idle for the data, which are provided by the CPU.

As a double-check, try to look at the CPU percentage while training on both GPUs and check whether it is almost always at 100%.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check if there are some bugs that are leading to this phenomenon.
It's true that the CPU percentage is full. Thanks, that's what I didn't notice.

Comment: Hi, I'm so glad to tell you that I found the code "torch.cuda.empty_cache()" caused this problem. I removed it, and now only cuda:1 has data. But I don't know why it can result in this problem.